# Viewing Only One Folder At A Time In Code Editor

Tags: file-management, text-editors, visual-studio, sublime-text, tree-view

I use FL Studio for music production, and one of the best features that it has is the ability to "View Only One Folder Content At A Time", such that if I expand a folder in the integrated file browser, the others instantly collapse.  There are times (rarely) when this is undesirable, but for the most part, it seems like this is the most logical behavior for visually navigating file trees.

I'm looking for a way to have this functionality implemented in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio or the file browser in Sublime Text; or really any code editor with a file browser.  I may have a folder where I need to edit a file and that folder has 30 other files, and then I have to expand another folder; and after awhile, everything is expanded, and then I can't find anything without manually collapsing all of them, and then I may need to open another one a second later.

Does anyone know if this is built in, or easily acheievable with Sublime or VS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about even FILE managers which do it. In Tree control. Eg, take a look at UltraExplorer, or Cubic Explorer, or TotalCmd. They don't have (when I saw at 2012). Try to ask this at filemanager field.

Comment: If you get a chance, dowload the demo of FL Studio and check it out.  I guarantee you will want this feature in your code editor.

Comment: What is "filemanger field"?

Comment: Maybe find this feature in some filemanager: CUbic Explorer, XYPlorer.

Comment: Don't think so.